# Cannot add participants to calendar events

Tags: calendar

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3.

Last week I deleted an event from my calendar.  Since then, I have not been able to add participants to my events.  I've gone through all the settings. I have also rebooted, but it doesn't help. Can anyone advise?

Comment: What happened when you tried to add a participant? Was there an error message? Did it just not do anything? Was the button for adding participants missing or greyed out?